# Como usar o efeito transition em um display?

Tags: css, wordpress, css3, css-transições

Bom dia, Tudo bem?

Estou tentando, porém ainda não consegui usar o efeito *transition* para deixar suave a troca de `display:block` para `display:none` e virse e versa.

Estou usando JS para quando o usuário rolar a página aplicar o `display:none`, porém isso está acontecendo meio rápido, queria que acontecesse mais lento para deixar um efeito mais natural, alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
var $JQuery = jQuery.noConflict()
$JQuery(function() {
            $JQuery(window).on("scroll", function() {
                if($JQuery(window).scrollTop() > 80) {
                    document.getElementById('headerTota').style.display = 'none';
                } else {
                    document.getElementById('headerTota').style.display = 'block';
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Cara não existem "meio display" vc não consegue essa transição de forma suave, no caso do display é tipo Sim ou Não. Para fazer isso vc quer tem que usar Opacity, dessa forma vc consegue fazer uma transição suave

Answer (score 0):

Caso alguém necessite, não é o que precisava porém está melhor do que estava antes, segue o codigo:

```
.ajusHeader{background: transparent; height:0px; overflow:hidden;-webkit-transition: height 2.25s ease-in-out;-moz-transition: height 2.25s ease-in-out;-ms-transition: height 2.25s ease-in-out; -o-transition: height 2.25s ease-in-out; transition: height 2.25s ease-in-out;}

.BlocoMenuTotBg{width: 100%;margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;}
.ajusMenu{top: 0;z-index: 999999;position: fixed;}

var $JQuery = jQuery.noConflict()
$JQuery(function() {
            $JQuery(window).on("scroll", function() {
                if($JQuery(window).scrollTop() > 80) {
                    $JQuery(".headerTopBg").addClass("ajusHeader");
                } else {
                    $JQuery(".headerTopBg").removeClass("ajusHeader");
                }
                if($JQuery(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
                    $JQuery(".BlocoMenuTotBg").addClass("ajusMenu");
                }else{
                    $JQuery(".BlocoMenuTotBg").removeClass("ajusMenu");
                }
            });
        });
```